# Update iisnode bits on your web roles?

Tags: azure, iisnode

When using the [Powershell cmdlets for Node on Azure,](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools) specifically `Add-AzureNodeWebRole`, you get the startup task all set up to deploy iisnode to your Azure instance, including an `iisnode.msi` installer.

What happens when `iisnode` is updated and you'd like to deploy the new `iisnode` bits?  Do you need to manually go through and add a new .msi to all your roles?  If so, where would you get that .msi?  I look at [the iisnode repo](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode#readme) and only see a big .exe installer.

Answer (score 0):

I see many many MSIs: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/downloads.

Yes, I would think you'll want to update iisnode.msi in your apps if you want to use a newer build.

Comment: Ah okay.  In the SDK they call it iisnode.msi, I'll assume for Azure I would pull down the most recent x64 "core" (rather than full) install.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the location of the most recent iisnode MSIs has moved to https://github.com/windowsazure/iisnode/downloads.

Comment: Renaming iisnode-core-iis7-v0.1.17-x64.msi to iisnode.msi and placing it in the webrole's /bin folder seemed to work.  Thanks.